# Windows dev Dashboard detects to many languages

Tags: windows-store-apps, windows-store

I published an application via the Windows Dev Dashboard.
My App (Universal Windows 8.1) has set resources in the manifest like this:

```
<Resources>
 <Resource Language="x-generate" />
</Resource>
```

In the Strings I habe the following directory schema:

Strings

```
de
  Resources.resw
en
  Resources.resw
es
  Resources.resw
```

After the first submission I had to add descriptions in

EN

EN-US

DE

ES

This seems OK - since I have to gibe a fully qualified language tag which was en-US.

But with the next version I published I had to add

EN

EN-US

DE

DE-DE

ES

ES-ES

Since DE and DE-DE is totally the same text (images) I don't want to maintain an extra set of descriptions / images.

How can I get rid of these (de-DE, es-ES - and if possible en-US) languages in the dashboard?